# Font size in ioslides markdown presentation title page

Tags: css, r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Trying to alter the default text size of the title page from an ioslides presentation but failing:

```
---
title: "My title is a bit too long to fully fit on the title page. I would really like to alter the font size to  provide a better fit. I have limited CSS skills to do so"
author: "My Name"
date: "29 March 2016"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
  css: slide.css
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation.
```

Where my style.css file is:

```
h1 { font-size: 12px;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, spacing/indentation/tab is important in YAML (notice the additional tab on the `css` line):

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: slide.css
```

This is not perfect and hopefully somebody else can chime in, but you can adjust `.title-slide` class with `hgroup` and `h1` tags with:

```
.title-slide hgroup h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

Note: You will want to modify `letter-spacing` to `0` (as opposed to the original rendered `3px`) in the current example.

Comment: I see. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: How do we change font size for the title for a specific slide only?